# Errors while creating a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I am not able to create a collection. It gives a sentence in the mongo shell - `Display all 169 possibilities? (y or n)`. The code is -

```
db.Lead.insert( 
{ LeadID: 1, 
  MasterAccountID: 100, 
  LeadName: 'Sarah', 
  LeadEmailID : 'sarah@hmail.com', 
  LeadPhoneNumber : '2132155445', 
  Details : [{ StateID: 1, 
              TaskID : 1, 
              Assigned By : 1001, 
              TimeStamp : '10:00:00', 
              StatusID : 1 }
            ]
} 
)
```

Not sure what the issue is. Please help me out with the same.

Regards.

Comment: are you sure that you are actually in the mongo shell?  That message looks more like *nix shell message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact there is a space in `Assigned By` everything looks good.

I am able to insert it properly.

```
> db.Lead.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("517ebe75278e0557fd167eb7"),
        "LeadID" : 1,
        "MasterAccountID" : 100,
        "LeadName" : "Sarah",
        "LeadEmailID" : "sarah@hmail.com",
        "LeadPhoneNumber" : "2132155445",
        "Details" : [
                {
                        "StateID" : 1,
                        "TaskID" : 1,
                        "AssignedBy" : 1001,
                        "TimeStamp" : "10:00:00",
                        "StatusID" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Ajay. This was really helpful. I wanted to know if there is some GUI or Editor you know of where coding becomes easy for MongoDB, atleast to know the errors or the warnings.

Comment: sure. Here you go. [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) or [RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com/) for PHP with Mongo

Comment: Thanks Ajay. Will surely try my hands on them.